# JQuery .append() проблема.

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Столкнулся с проблемой, append первый раз создает нормальный div после выполнения функции, но все последующие по нажатию на кнопку "Send" - он **создает два дива**, по нажатию на третий раз на кнопку отправки - он **создает 3 дива**. И так далее по последующих отправках текста. В чем моя проблема?

Задача состояла в одиночном создании Div по нажатию на button. 
Сейчас при каждом клике создается вот такое вот поле. 
String 1 - 1 клик , String 2 - 2 клик и так далее.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
$('#textbox').click(function(event) {
  if (event.which = 13) {
    if ($('#enter').prop("checked")) {
      $('#textbox').val('');
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
  $('#send').click(function() {
    var userMessage = $('#textbox').val();
    $('#textbox').val('');
    createDiv = '<div class="user-message">' + userMessage + '</div>';
    $('#user-message').append(createDiv);
  });

});
```

Comment: вынеси навешивание обработчика клика на `#send` из обработчика клика `#textbox`

Comment: @Grundy можно по-подробнее?

Comment: Каждый раз когда ты кликаешь на `#textbox` у тебя _добавляется обработчик_ к `#send`, то есть два раза кликнул на `#textbox` - на `#send` будет два обработчика, следовательно при клике на `#send` функция выполнится дважды и т.д.

Comment: @Grundy Да, все верно, запили ответ с кодом я приму, спасибо)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Навешивание обработчика клика на `#send` находится внутри обработчика клика #textbox, поэтому каждый раз, когда ты кликаешь на `#textbox` у тебя добавляется обработчик к `#send`, то есть два раза кликнул на #textbox - на #send будет два обработчика, следовательно при клике на #send функция выполнится дважды и т.д.

Для решения нужно вынести навешивание обработчика клика для `#send`

```
$('#textbox').click(function(event) {
  if (event.which = 13) {
    if ($('#enter').prop("checked")) {
      $('#textbox').val('');
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
});
$('#send').click(function() {
  var userMessage = $('#textbox').val();
  $('#textbox').val('');
  createDiv = '<div class="user-message">' + userMessage + '</div>';
  $('#user-message').append(createDiv);
});
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное за помощь, разобрался.